# How to get value from string stored as object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I have stored values as json object in my database after get those values i have this result

```
'["{ zone :1, cat_id : 1, subcat : 2}","{ zone :1, cat_id : 2, subcat : 2}","{ 
zone :1, cat_id : 2, subcat : 3}"]'
```

then i convert it with json_decode to array then i got this result

```
"{ zone :1, cat_id : 1, subcat : 2}"
```

But  i am not able to get the values of zone , cat_id and subcat in php

so is ther any way to get this value , also i have many records in loop like this.So I wants some efficient way to get this value.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are using.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? That would make it much easier for us to find out where the issue is and help you solve the problem. Without seeing the code, all anyone can do is just _guess_.

Comment: Your original string should be something like `'[{ "zone":1, "cat_id" : 1, "subcat" : 2},` to make it a complete JSON value

Comment: Your string is valid JSON string upto one level only. Second level is not a valid JSON. You should use decode json @ both level thenstore them into database.

Comment: And If you don't want to correct your JSON string, there is another way. use some regex to remove ",{,}," and then explode value with "," you will get your output array!!!

Comment: I am amking a dynamic array of this object like string

Comment: $data[] .= '{ zone :'.$breakage[0][0].', cat_id : '. $breakage[0][1] . ', subcat : '. $breakage[0][2] .'}';

Answer (score 0):

Well actually, the serialized array you have, is an array of strings representing JSON objects.

So you need to `json_decode` the full array **and** every single value of the array.

```
$values = '["{ zone :1, cat_id : 1, subcat : 2}","{ zone :1, cat_id : 2, subcat : 2}","{ 
zone :1, cat_id : 2, subcat : 3}"]';
$decodedValues = json_decode($values);
$firstValue = json_decode($decodedValues[0]);
```

There you whould have the decoded value :)

OR (if you can edit the format of the string you consume)

You could change the initial format of the values, for it to be a simple array of objects. If you want (and can of course) do that, you would simply need to remove the `"` inside the serialized array.

Instead of `'["{ zone: 1 ...}"]'` simply `'[{"zone": 1 ...}]'`

Comment: Oh that's right, for it to be a valid JSON, you need to add double quote around every property name `{ "zone": 1 }` for example

Comment: It should be `'[{"zone": 1 ...}]'` not `'[{zone: 1 ...}]'`

Comment: are you able to edit the format that is serialized ?

Comment: can you accept the response then, or is there something missing?

Comment: i can do it like this ["{ "zone" :1, "cat_id" : 2, "subcat" : 1}","{ "zone" :1, "cat_id" : 2, "subcat" : 3}","{ "zone" :1, "cat_id" : 4, "subcat" : 1}","{ "zone" :1, "cat_id" : 4, "subcat" : 3}"]

Comment: Where does the data come from? If you create it in the php file, you can directly write php arrays : 
`[ 
  [ "zone" => 1, "cat_id" => 2 ],
]`

Comment: Oh I just re-read you post, and the json is in your DB. So the nice thing to do, would be having real PHP array on one side, and json_encode them just before saving to DB. On the otherside, the json_decode should work as expeted :)

Comment: i am doing json_encode bofore saving.but it is not working

Comment: hum ? What data are you encoding exactly?

Comment: $data[] .= '{ "zone" :'.$breakage[0][0].', "cat_id" : '. $breakage[0][1] . ', "subcat" : '. $breakage[0][2] .'}';

Comment: after loop is completed then i am doing this $result = json_encode($data) and sending $result value to my database

Comment: Try then with php arrays instead of json strings : `$data[] = ["zone" => $breakage[0][0] ...];`